# Batch, adding quotes to argument stops reg from working

Tags: windows, batch-file

So i tried to make a batch file that runs when a txt file is opened.

```
reg add HKCR\txtfile\shell\open\command /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %0 /f
```

So far so good. But when i open the text document theres an error due to spaces in %0.

```
reg add HKCR\txtfile\shell\open\command /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%0" /f
```

This doesnt give me an error, but the registry value doesnt change.

```
reg add HKCR\txtfile\shell\open\command /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d ^"%0^" /f
```

Same thing.
So whats my problem here?

Comment: Why REG_EXPAND_SZ? There's nothing to expand so just use REG_SZ!

Answer (score 1):

The escape character in this case, *(complete lack of consistency, I know)*, is the back slash:

```dos
Reg Add "HKCR\txtfile\shell\open\command" /VE /D \"%~0\" /F >Nul
```

Comment: C:/Documents and settings/No Body/Desktop/txt.txt is not a valid Win32 application. upon opening a text file :/

Comment: If you take a look at the registry key you can quite clearly see that the data is a quoted string containing the initial script's path. That is exactly what you asked for, the fact the entry does not do what you wanted is irrelevant.

Comment: its not changed the key, i had to manually put quotes. (windows xp is os btw) @Compo

Comment: Please tell me exactly what command you want to run from the registry upon the invokation of a text file.

Comment: "*insert location of batch file here*"

Comment: That's not a command, it is a question. What you need to understand is that the initial question suggests that the batch file that runs is the same file you ran to create the registry command in the first place, so there must be something else in that file other than the `reg add` command and a method of preventing certain parts of that file from running when the registry data command is invoked. Please try to be more specific and provide more information because what you have supplied so far is insufficient to overcome your current problems.

Comment: i give up trying to explain this, 
 
"insert location of batch file here" 

this means i dont know where the batch file is, and thats all thats in my batch file

Comment: You need to have at least three commands. One in the batch file, that performs the reg add command; One in the registry that runs the batch file again when you try to open a text file; Another one in the batch file that is executed when the registry entry runs it. You have two of them now, the third is a mystery. I need to know the end goal, when a text file is double clicked, you want it to instead run a batch file, when that batch file runs, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: im still stuck at step 1. the reg add command doesnt complain but doesnt do anything. it does NOTHING to the registry for some reason.

Comment: A revisit of this question has prompted this response. As you are adding to a registry location which is protected, the script will need to be **Run as administrator**! Apologies for not having seen your comment earlier.